# How to get the broker tab in flower working with Airflow and RabbitMq over SSL?

Tags: rabbitmq, airflow, celery, airflow-2.x, flower

In Flower the broker tab is not showing the queues when using it together with Airflow 2.3.4, RabbitMQ over SSL and Celery Executor

As far as I understand Flower needs two parameters to make this tab work:

1. broker_url, e.g. amqp://username:password@somedomain.amazonaws.com:5671/?ssl=true
2. http_api, e.g. https://username:password@somedomain.amazonaws.com:15672/api/

I don't understand how to configure Airflow so that this information is passed correctly to Flower, and Flower is using ssl with RabbitMQ and connecting to the http_api on  port 15672.

If I hack broker.py in Flower package the broker tab in Flower is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the http_api as extra parameter when starting the flower process:

```
airflow celery flower  --help
...
-a BROKER_API, --broker-api BROKER_API
...
```